# Unexpected results when handling strings in PHP

Tags: php, string, file-upload, file-processing

Thank you for your time to look at this for me.

Background: I am processing OFX/QFX files for a personal finance project.  I have written the code in C# and it executes perfectly.  I am able to create my import object, process the OFX/QFX file line by line and output the a fore mentioned object to the console.  However I am porting this to PHP for use in a web application that is not written on the .Net Framework.

Problem:  A file is uploaded by a user and passed to my PHP file. When reading the file line by line using `$line = fgets($file);` I am not getting the expected results.  I know for a fact that the file is open and that the line is being read. However; when I put `var_dump($line)` immediately after the variable is assigned I receive
`"string(15) "ENG ""` when what I should get is:

```
<LANGUAGE>ENG
```

My processing model heavily depends on the ability to read the tag portion of the string, but because PHP seems to be stripping it out, my code does not perform as expected.

Question: Can anyone tell me why I am not receiving the full string value when using fgets()? Also is there a more correct way to do this?  I am quite knowledgeable in .Net but PHP is a little new to me so I'm assuming it's just a quirk of the PHP language that I do not understand.

Thank you

Comment: What happens if you just echo the line out?

Comment: The variable is correct, but once it gets printed to your browser the tag is ignored because it tries to treat it as HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see with your var_dump() result, it's a 15 char long string. Your problem is probably that the `<LANGUAGE>` tag is not shown but "there".

Try using `htmlspecialchars($line);` instead. But I normally recommend the usage of var_dump(), since it shows very clearly the type and the length of a variable value.

Comment: As was your post.  The culmination of all your posts helped to guide me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `<LANGUAGE>` is parsed by the browser, considered an invalid HTML tag and ignored.

Right-click view source in the browser to view the real output.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  Knowing this little bit of information helped me to realize that the issue was in the writing of my code and not the code itself.  This has definitely put me on the right path.  Thank you again very much!

Answer (score 0):

I would venture to guess if `<LANGUAGE>ENG` is what you are expecting to be outputted to the screen then it probably is.  Your web browser will see that and attempt to parse it as a tag and only display the data associated with that tag and not the tag itself.  Not an issue with PHP.   Try echoing the line using pre tags

```
echo '<pre>' . $line . '</pre>';
```

Comment: This was also a help to me.  Thank you!